How to pass a custom header property in typescript Playwright?
Using playwright to automate testing of an API which requires a token passed in a custom header property named 'x-my-api-token'. What's the most effective way to implement an API method with a custom property like this?
This is the code I've written.
import { request, test, APIRequestContext } from "@playwright/test"

class DataApi {
    constructor(private context: APIRequestContext) { }

    public async getDataForEntity(token: string, entityId?: string): Promise<JSON> {
        const response = await this.context.get(`https://api.example.com/activities/${entityId}`, {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                'x-my-api-token': token
            },
        });
        return await response.json();
    }
}

Running this test code passes the token to the Authorization header property, but the 'x-my-api-token' property is not present in the request header.
test("Data API", ({page}) => {
    let dataApi: DataApi;

    test.beforeAll(async () => {
        dataApi = new DataApi(request);
    });
    const token = "sample_token";
    const entityId = "12345";
    test.step("should fetch data for an entity", async () => {
        const data = await dataApi.getDataForEntity(token, entityId);
        console.log(data);
    });
});

I've also tried using page.setExtraHTTPHeaders but I get the same result.
    test("should fetch data for an entity", async ({page}) => {
        page.setExtraHTTPHeaders{
        'x-my-api-token': token
        }
        const data = await dataApi.getDataForEntity(token, entityId);
        console.log(data);
    });


Custom headers work fine for me:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

test("Allows custom header", async ({request}) => {
  const res = await request.get("https://httpbin.org/get", {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "x-my-api-token": "42",
    },
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  expect(data.headers["X-My-Api-Token"]).toBe("42");
});

Output:
$ npx playwright test pw1.test.js

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 pw1.test.js:3:1 › Allows custom header (539ms)

  1 passed (963ms)

Note that the header words were capitalized by Playwright, which is the expected behavior.
Please share a minimal, reproducible example that can be executed to produce the error.

This answer is correct. If you don't have it Gary means only that your API endpoint doesn't return sent headers in JSON responce
